# USBTMC in Python

Tags: python, usb

I am trying to talk to my Clarke-Hess Phase Meter 6000A through USB. I am using https://github.com/python-ivi/python-usbtmc/tree/master/usbtmc for this purpose. Now, when I connect my USB cable and do `lsusb`, it yields,

> Bus 001 Device 027: ID 0403:b972 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd

as my recognized device, so I simply used `usbtmc` and got the following error:

[image]

#### Code

```
>>> import usbtmc
>>> inst = usbtmc.Instrument(0x0403,0xb972)
Find USBTMC instrument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "usbtmc/usbtmc.py", line 229, in __init__
    raise UsbtmcException("Device not found", 'init')
usbtmc.usbtmc.UsbtmcException: Device not found [init]
```

But when I looked into usbtmc.py, I found that in the list_devices(), usb.util.find_descriptor() is used with parameters as USBTMC_bInterfaceClass = 0xFE, and USBTMC_bInterfaceSubClass = 3, which makes it unable to detect my device which has descriptors as both bInterfaceClass and bInterfaceSubClass = 0xff.

Then I changed USBTMC_bInterfaceClass and USBTMC_bInterfaceSubClass to 0xff, and then it yielded:

[image]

#### Code

```
>>> import usbtmc
>>> inst = usbtmc.Instrument(0x0403,0xb972)
Find USBTMC instrument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "usbtmc/usbtmc.py", line 283, in __init__
    self.get_capabilities()
  File "usbtmc/usbtmc.py", line 299, in get_capabilities
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 971, in ctrl_transfer
    self.__get_timeout(timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 819, in ctrl_transfer
    timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 552, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 32] Pipe error
```

At least, in this case it detected my device, but it threw some other error.

How can I fix this issue? The manual says the device is completely compatible with GPIB-like commands. In fact, I have tested the device with GPIB, and it works fine.

Comment: can you pealse edit the relevant text from the images into your question?

Comment: You linked to images of your console, which show the commands you used and the error message. Put this text (commands and error messages) directly into your question, so it is easier for others to answer (and maybe revise the formatting while you're at it).

Comment: FTDI? Sounds like a simple USB-Serial converter. Linux does support them out-of-the-box; Newer Windowses, too - afaik. Did you try PySerial?

Comment: The images are unreadable. Please add **all** **required** infformation as text to your question. Read about [mcve]

Comment: @Olaf, Its not USB-Serial converter converter. The equipment has type-B male usb port on its back, and I am using type-B to type-A usb cable (the printer cable).
I have added commands and errors that I faced.

Comment: The cable is no indicator (and is completely normal). However, your problem.

Comment: The problem is that ideally the device should respond to my commands but it's not. When I changed the descriptors that code was using, then it found the device but started throwing pipe error. I want to ask if anyone can help me talk to device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Olaf, you were right in asking. It is to be used as a serial device using PySerial. Here is how it worked, the problems I faced, and their solution.

1. I connected the device through the USB cable, and did `lsusb`:

   ```
   root@pelcon:~# lsusb

   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0403:b972 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:114f Syntek
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
   ```
2. Next, I checked for detection of the device as:

   ```
   root@pelcon:~# ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*

   ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB**: No such file or directory
   ```
3. Then I looked into this matter and found "In recent kernels (definitely with 14.04 LTS), the ftdi_sio module no longer accepts the product and vendor options." in *[Can't open port /dev/ttyUSB0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525016/cant-open-port-dev-ttyusb0)*.
4. I also checked `dmesg | tail` which showed me that FTDI USB was detected, but it was disconnected.
5. Then I did two things:

   a. Created `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-axe027.rules` with contents `ATTR{idProduct}=="b972", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -q ftdi_sio product=0xb972 vendor=0x0403"`. I restarted and again did `dmesg | tail`. But it was still undetected. Steps are given in *[Can't program with USB adapter except through `sudo nautilus ubuntu`](http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/showthread.php?22843-cant-program-with-usb-adapter-except-through-sudo-nautilus-ubuntu/page2%3E)*

   b. Then I searched further, and this time I found *[Attaching USB-Serial device with custom PID to ttyUSB0 on embedded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67936/attaching-usb-serial-device-with-custom-pid-to-ttyusb0-on-embedded)*, where I did:

   1. Unplugged the device
   2. `modprobe ftdi_sio`
   3. `echo 0403 b972 >/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id`
   4. Plugged in the device

   5.

   ```
   ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*

   crw-rw---- 1 root usbtmc 188, 0 Jul 23 11:33 /dev/ttyUSB0
   ```

   6.

   ```
   dmesg | tail
   [ 1162.348082] usb 1-1.2: Product: 6000A Phase Meter
   [ 1162.348086] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: clarke-hess
   [ 1162.348089] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 187
   [ 1162.350801] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
   [ 1162.350837] usb 1-1.2: Detected FT232BM
   [ 1162.350840] usb 1-1.2: Number of endpoints 2
   [ 1162.350842] usb 1-1.2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
   [ 1162.350844] usb 1-1.2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
   [ 1162.350846] usb 1-1.2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
   [ 1162.351284] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0`
   ```

So, this way my device was detected, and I was able to communicate to it via PySerial as:

```
import serial, time
se = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)
print('Open USB serial connection:')
print '\t', se

print se.portstr    # Confirm which port was really used
se.write("*IDN?\n")
data = se.readline()
time.sleep(2)
print data
se.close()
```

which gave the output as:

Open USB serial connection:

```
Serial<id=0xb329574c, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

/dev/ttyUSB0

**CLARKE-HESS,6000A,187,1.07**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
usbtmc.list_devices()
```

or

```
usbtmc.find_device()
```

The former doesn't require arguments. The latter is defined [here](https://github.com/python-ivi/python-usbtmc/blob/master/usbtmc/usbtmc.py#L136).